# jQuery position problem with Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, position

When I alert the value `.position().left`, it returns 0 on [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). With other browsers it returns the actual number. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please post more code, specifically what element you are calling `position` on, and perhaps some HTML/CSS to see what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Webkit based browsers (like Chrome and Safari) can access images `width` and `height` properties  only after images have been fully loaded. Other browsers can access this information as soon as just the DOM is loaded (they don't need to load the images entirely to know their size).

So, if you have images in your page, with Webkit based browsers you should access `offset` information after the `$(window).load` event fires, and not after the `$(document).ready` event.

Comment: And sometimes even then it doesn't work. Another option is to manually set the image sizes in your css.

Comment: And apparently webkit can only access text width and height properties after window.load  as well.  Seems silly that even Internet Explorer can get it right.  The last one I thought would get it wrong was webkit.

Answer (score 9):

By reading comments from http://api.jquery.com/position/, there are several ways to fix this. 
The one I found working is

> Ajaho  [Moderator] :This plugin function fixes problems
>   with wrong position in Chrome

```
jQuery.fn.aPosition = function() {
    thisLeft = this.offset().left;
    thisTop = this.offset().top;
    thisParent = this.parent();

    parentLeft = thisParent.offset().left;
    parentTop = thisParent.offset().top;

    return {
        left: thisLeft-parentLeft,
        top: thisTop-parentTop
    };
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Webkit can be too fast sometimes, but it's often taken care of in jQuery. You can debug using something like:

```
var v, elem = $('.myElement');
window.setTimeout(function() {
    v = elem.position().left;
    console.log(v);
    if (v) {
        return false;
    }
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1);
}, 1);
```

This will check if and when the position is available. If you are logging "0" in infinity, the `position().left` is "never" available and you need to debug elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks - this was also the reason why `jQuery.offset()` was returning incorrect (nonzero) values - it looks like my CSS positioning was causing Chrome to lay out the document twice (or something).  Calling `offset` too soon returned the position of the elements as they would be without CSS.

Comment: +1 I had this problem yesterday. Position was incorrect even in a simple `$(function(){console.log($('img').position().top);});` but was correct when using the same code in a click event later.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem..

I fixed it using: `.offset().left` instead. But be aware that are not the same:
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

`.position().left` worked in Chrome in some tests I did, using 
a similar approach than David (the value was available since the
first try).

In my "real" application failed even
reading the position on click event (which may eliminate any loading
speed problem).
Some comments (in other forum) say it may be related 
to the use of `display:inline-block`. However I couldn't
reproduce the problem using `inline-block`. So it may
be other thing.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a bit outdated since the questions dates from 2010 but this did the trick for my positioning problems in Chrome:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  p = $('element').offset();
  // et cetera
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery(window).load() instead of jQuery(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by placing the javascript code in a document ready just before the closing of the body tag

That way it executes the code after it has loaded everything

```
    <body>
        <div>content</div>
        <div class='footer'>footer</div>
        .
        .
        .

        <script type='text/javascript>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              var footer_position = $(".footer").offset().top;
              console.log(footer_position);
            });
        </script>
     </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this function to correct it.

```
function getElementPosition(id) {
          var offsetTrail = document.getElementById(id);
          var offsetBottom = 0;
          var offsetTop = 0;
          while (offsetTrail) {
              offsetBottom += offsetTrail.offsetBottom;
              offsetTop += offsetTrail.offsetTop;
              offsetTrail = offsetTrail.offsetParent;
          }

          return {
              bottom: offsetBottom,
              toppos: offsetTop
          };
      }
```