# jquery mouse offset position different in firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

Hello I have a tool tip I am making with jquery, that loads the alt value from an image into a floating div thats being positioned by jquery offset().  My code works in Chrome/Safari but not Firefox.

In Chrome the tooltip appears above an icon which sits right of the label for this item.  (This is also done in a modal box, maybe this is the problem?

I am still somewhat new to this so please excuse my code.

```
$("img.more_info, div.option_item_wrap label").live('mouseover', function(e) {
    optionIcon = $(this).closest('div').find('img.more_info');
    optionInfoContent = optionIcon.attr('alt');

    if(optionInfoContent != undefined) {
        findImage = $(this).closest('div').find('span.option_item_image');
        $("body").append('<div id="option_info"><p>' + optionInfoContent + '</p><div id="option_info_tail"></div></div>');
        findImage.clone().prependTo('div#option_info p');
        toolTipHeight = $('div#option_info').height();
        findIconPost = optionIcon.offset();
        topPos = findIconPost.top - (toolTipHeight + 20);
        leftPos = findIconPost.left - 80;

        $('div#option_info').css('top', topPos).css('left', leftPos).fadeIn();
    };
}).live('mouseout', function() {
    $('div#option_info').remove();
});
```

Comment: So Firefox and Chrome are returning different results from offset... off by about 15px, any ideas?

Comment: does `console.log( findIconPost )` return different values too?

Comment: yes the returned values are different

Comment: what about `optionIcon[0].offsetLeft` and `optionIcon[0].offsetTop`

Comment: yes those are also returning different results in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if($.browser.mozilla){
        topPos = findIconPost.top - (toolTipHeight + 90);
    }
```

This was the only solution I could come up with, I just adjusted the offset for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.live` function is not recommended due to [various reasons](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Try using a more typical approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.more_info, div.option_item_wrap label").mouseover(function() {
        // Your code
    });
});
```

This may or may not solve your problem but if it does, then you were experiencing the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173040/jquery-position-problem-with-chrome).