# Having 2 sticky headers, one that switches, one that doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I asked a question here a couple weeks ago about [getting sticky headers to switch out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a), much like they do in the iPhone Instagram app. I was pleased when someone answered my question with exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I was playing around with it in a different setting and I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the original that works: (http://codepen.io/chrissp26/full/gBrdo)

Here is what's acting up: (http://codepen.io/anon/full/sAHuy)

Basically I need the sub-headers to switch and 'push up' like they do in the first example, while keeping the main header section, the section on top, the same. The sub-sections need to push under the main header, not over it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know and understand what the script @chris provided does?

Comment: Somewhat. It switches the styles from fixed to absolute when pushing up.

Comment: @ryanSrich, please post the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery code is waiting for the element to touch the top of the screen and not 45 picels from the top like how you stated in the CSS. See lines 322-337.

Comment: I see the code. Should I change the scrollTop? Anyway I can have it engage down lower, say 45 pixels as you suggested or would I need to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: rewrite the part that checks if the element is at 0px from the top of the screen. Right now the script doesn't add the fixed position until it reaches the top.

Comment: I tried adding "top: 45px;" but it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried adding 45px to the scrollTop(); but nothing. Where should I add the spacing in the jQuery? ...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sAHuy

Comment: `top: 45px` is the CSS of the class that jQuery adds. I don't use codepen, so please find the WORKING script here: http://jsfiddle.net/k2PDm/1/

Comment: `var fromTop` should always be the same as where you changed `top: 45px` in the CSS