# Instagram style content relative navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the Instagram style newsfeed navigation bar, where the fixed navigation bar is relative to the user content, for web applications. This is what i'm trying to achieve: http://i.gifboom.com/medias/396af3500ff24fedbc528ae640d838ed@2x.gif

I was looking for similar implementation on twitter bootstrap but couldn't find any.
Are there any existing implementations on this UI for web applications that i can readily use?

Answer (score 1):

Code Pen has a good example as mentioned in this Stack Overflow. Is this what you're looking for?

[Getting a sticky header to "push up", like in Instagram's iPhone app using CSS and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a)

Comment: thks bansay! its exactly what i'm looking for!