# Sticky element within parent element with translate3d(0,0,0) property

Tags: css, css-transitions, hardware-acceleration

Is it even possible?
Are there any techniques that will allow me to keep an element sticky as I scroll in an overflowing div?

Comment: yes, how about adding a fixed layer on top of that? edit: cancel that, I just realized what you meant

Comment: maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a