# how to remove fixed class from div when div scrolls to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fixed

I have a div that once the top reaches the top of the browser it stayed fixed. Now I need it to remove the position fixed when the user scrolls to the top of another div, and I need the div to stay where the next div is, for when the user scrolls back up, not sure how to go about doing that. Here is what I got.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t600wkod/

Any help is appreciated!

```
var top = $('.part1').offset().top - parseFloat($('.part1').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,0));


$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, add the fixed class
      $('.part1').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('.part1').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: _user scrolls to the top of another div_ ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Sorry about my wording, I mean when the user is scrolling and the div under is on the browser, it removes the fixed class, because right now it just sticks on top of the other div, because its fixed.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: @RayonDabre https://jsfiddle.net/t600wkod/

Comment: Have a look at this, http://codepen.io/trymedo/pen/YXWvOo.

Comment: or you could also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13293684/1320407

Comment: @anurag Awesome references! helped alot, thank you

Comment: @Matt Glad to help, cheers.