# Make specific header sticky depending on user's scroll position on page in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In Angular I need to make a panel header sticky depending on where the user's scroll position is on the page.

I believe there are two ways of doing what I want to achieve. One of them is with pure css using position: sticky. You can see my commented out css code in app.component.css. This technique has nothing to do with Angular and will work.

The other way which is more browser compliant is using JavaScript which is where I am struggling using Angular vs plain html/css/js.

Using Angular I am using @HostListener to access the window scroll. This gives me access to the current window scroll position. I believe this is a good starting point.

The part that I am unable to figure out is how to check the position of each panel header using offsetTop() and if the position of the panel header being checked is less than the scroll position I want to add the sticky class, otherwise remove it.

I know for a fact this would be a bit easier if I made panel a component of its own. However, this is currently not an option.

Please see what I have so far at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7pgrx

Answer (score 0):

Follow me headers - that is what your desired featured is called.

There is already a good working code pen out there by Chris Spittles:
https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

*In case that the link will stop working one day:*

**html:**

```
<h1>Multiple Sticky Titles with CSS and JS</h1>
<section class="explanation">
  <p>On some mobile platforms there are lists that group items under multiple headings. As you scroll through the list, the current title or heading follows you until you reach the next one at which point the current one is pushed up and the new title or heading docks to the top. <br>This snippet emulates this functionality.</p>
  <p>
    I created this originally because of this
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a/13293684#13293684" target="_blank">question</a> on stack overflow.
  </p>

</section>

<div class="followMeBar">A</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">B</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">C</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

**css:**

```
.followMeBar {
  background: #e64a19;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.followMeBar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

.followMeBar.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}


/* For aesthetics only ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 200 1.2em "Segoe UI Light", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  background: #039be4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  strong {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Black";
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

.explanation {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  p {
    max-width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var stickyHeaders = (function() {

  var $window = $(window),
      $stickies;

  var load = function(stickies) {

    if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

      $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

        var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');

        $thisSticky
            .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
            .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
              .parent()
              .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());             
      });

      $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {
          _whenScrolling();     
      });
    }
  };

  var _whenScrolling = function() {

    $stickies.each(function(i) {            

      var $thisSticky = $(this),
          $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

      if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {        

        var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
            $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

        $thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

        if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

          $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
        }

      } else {

        var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

        $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

        if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

          $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    load: load
  };
})();

$(function() {
  stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));
});
```

Comment: Megajin Thank you, I didn't realize followme headers was the name of the feature. This will help me do further research. However, my question was specifically how to do it in Angular without jQuery. In my posted stackblitz I am not far off.